# Issue adding to a Substring if a dsquery finds the same sAMAccountName

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I am editing a Powershell script that a colleague created before they left which I assume was created on an older version of Powershell/Activedirectoy. It is to create an AD account but I'm having an issue checking if a username already exists then carrying out an action if it does.

```
$UsernameInteger = 1
$sAMAccountName = $sn+$givenName.substring(0,$UsernameInteger)

# Check to see if the username is available in Active Directory
do
{
     if (dsquery user -samid $sAMAccountName)
     {
     $CreateUser = $False
     $UsernameInteger++
     $Username = $sn+$givenName.substring(0,$UsernameInteger)
     }

     Else

     {
     $CreateUser = $True
     }
}
Until ($CreateUser -eq $True)
```

When I run this code with an account with the same name I get the following error:

```
Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length"
At C:\AD Account Creation.ps1:43 char:5
+     $Username = $sn+$givenName.substring(0,$UsernameInteger)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

What I want is when the `$createuser = $false` then it will add the next letter of their `$givenName` to the `$username` and keep doing this until an account with the same `$sAMAccountName` is not found and the account can be created.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You've incremented the counter to a value bigger than the length of the `$givenName` string. You need to change the increment logic to something like:

```
if ($UsernameInteger -le $givenName.length) {
  $UsernameInteger++
}
```

This won't help if the username you pass in already exists in its entirety though, so you'll also need to handle that scenario